# Eclipse: Adding a jars folder to lib

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

I was trying to add a directory full of jars to the lib folder in my dynamic web project in eclipse. I am adding a directory because I want to maintain the new jars separate from the existing ones.

I added the new jars to the class path by selecting and adding all of them to the build path. When I run the web-application, I get class not found for the classes residing in the new jars directory.

However, the same procedure when implemented in a plain Java project works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT - 1: This has something to do with Deployment Assembly, I guess.
I added the jar path in that and it worked. Now, trying to apply for the complete directory.

Comment: Create a user library for your jars and add this library in classpath should work.

Comment: use Add External Class Folder or class folder option in eclipse

Comment: @Foolish Have tried that......same thing....class not found.

Comment: @raghavendra That doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1):

Reconfigure your build path. Remove web libraries and add web libraries again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When you deploy an application on tomcat (through eclipse or otherwise), all the jars have to be present in the lib folder.
If you are using a separate directory for some jars then you need to add an entry in the Deployment Assembly of your project to copy the jars in the lib folder. So, when you will actually run the application, the directory jars will be copied to lib.